# How to change address text returned in DirectionsLeg

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to change the text that is displayed in the returned directions from the Google Javascript API.  I want to prepend a business name to the front of each of the addresses returned in each leg of the route.  These will help our users better identify the location.

I am testing with this code (in my particular example there are 8 legs in the route:

```
        response.routes[0].legs[0].start_address = 'Store #0: ' + response.routes[0].legs[0].start_address;
        response.routes[0].legs[1].start_address = 'Store #1: ' + response.routes[0].legs[1].start_address;
        response.routes[0].legs[2].start_address = 'Store #2: ' + response.routes[0].legs[2].start_address;
        response.routes[0].legs[3].start_address = 'Store #3: ' + response.routes[0].legs[3].start_address;
        response.routes[0].legs[4].start_address = 'Store #4: ' + response.routes[0].legs[4].start_address;
        response.routes[0].legs[5].start_address = 'Store #5: ' + response.routes[0].legs[5].start_address;
        response.routes[0].legs[6].start_address = 'Store #6: ' + response.routes[0].legs[6].start_address;
        response.routes[0].legs[7].start_address = 'Store #7: ' + response.routes[0].legs[7].start_address;

        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
```

The problem is that my change is only showing up for the first leg, as shown in the screenshot linked below.. The request object, when queried, does reflect my changes before it goes into the setDirections method.  However, when I query the innerHTML after, the original directions are there.

I have found many examples online of this property being changed, and I find it weird that only the first leg is working, while the remaining do not.  I am still fairly new to Google Maps API, so am definitely not ruling out developer error.  Please advise, thanks!

Charles

[Output Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IA4GQ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the labels on the DirectionsDisplay panel after the first are using the `end_address`, not the `start_address`.

Add the labels to both.

```
  response.routes[0].legs[0].start_address = 'Store #0: ' + response.routes[0].legs[0].start_address;
  response.routes[0].legs[1].start_address = 'Store #1: ' + response.routes[0].legs[1].start_address;
  response.routes[0].legs[2].start_address = 'Store #2: ' + response.routes[0].legs[2].start_address;
  response.routes[0].legs[3].start_address = 'Store #3: ' + response.routes[0].legs[3].start_address;
  response.routes[0].legs[4].start_address = 'Store #4: ' + response.routes[0].legs[4].start_address;
  response.routes[0].legs[5].start_address = 'Store #5: ' + response.routes[0].legs[5].start_address;
  response.routes[0].legs[6].start_address = 'Store #6: ' + response.routes[0].legs[6].start_address;
  response.routes[0].legs[7].start_address = 'Store #7: ' + response.routes[0].legs[7].start_address;
  response.routes[0].legs[0].end_address = 'Store #1: ' + response.routes[0].legs[0].end_address;
  response.routes[0].legs[1].end_address = 'Store #2: ' + response.routes[0].legs[1].end_address;
  response.routes[0].legs[2].end_address = 'Store #3: ' + response.routes[0].legs[2].end_address;
  response.routes[0].legs[3].end_address = 'Store #4: ' + response.routes[0].legs[3].end_address;
  response.routes[0].legs[4].end_address = 'Store #5: ' + response.routes[0].legs[4].end_address;
  response.routes[0].legs[5].end_address = 'Store #6: ' + response.routes[0].legs[5].end_address;
  response.routes[0].legs[6].end_address = 'Store #7: ' + response.routes[0].legs[6].end_address;
  response.routes[0].legs[7].end_address = 'Store #8' + response.routes[0].legs[7].end_address;
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/so18m2yb/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
  var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 6,
    center: {
      lat: 41.85,
      lng: -87.65
    }
  });
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
}

function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
  var waypts = [];
  waypts.push({
    location: "New York, NY",
    stopover: true
  });
  waypts.push({
    location: "Boston, MA",
    stopover: true
  });
  waypts.push({
    location: "Chicago, IL",
    stopover: true
  });
  waypts.push({
    location: "Madison, WI",
    stopover: true
  });
  waypts.push({
    location: "Denver, CO",
    stopover: true
  });
  waypts.push({
    location: "Salt Lake City UT",
    stopover: true
  });
  waypts.push({
    location: "Mesa, AZ",
    stopover: true
  });

  waypts.push({
    location: "Las Vegas, NV",
    stopover: true
  });



  directionsService.route({
    origin: "Newark, NJ",
    destination: "Los Angeles, CA",
    waypoints: waypts,
    optimizeWaypoints: true,
    travelMode: 'DRIVING'
  }, function(response, status) {
    if (status === 'OK') {
      response.routes[0].legs[0].start_address = 'Store #0: ' + response.routes[0].legs[0].start_address;
      response.routes[0].legs[1].start_address = 'Store #1: ' + response.routes[0].legs[1].start_address;
      response.routes[0].legs[2].start_address = 'Store #2: ' + response.routes[0].legs[2].start_address;
      response.routes[0].legs[3].start_address = 'Store #3: ' + response.routes[0].legs[3].start_address;
      response.routes[0].legs[4].start_address = 'Store #4: ' + response.routes[0].legs[4].start_address;
      response.routes[0].legs[5].start_address = 'Store #5: ' + response.routes[0].legs[5].start_address;
      response.routes[0].legs[6].start_address = 'Store #6: ' + response.routes[0].legs[6].start_address;
      response.routes[0].legs[7].start_address = 'Store #7: ' + response.routes[0].legs[7].start_address;
      response.routes[0].legs[0].end_address = 'Store #1: ' + response.routes[0].legs[0].end_address;
      response.routes[0].legs[1].end_address = 'Store #2: ' + response.routes[0].legs[1].end_address;
      response.routes[0].legs[2].end_address = 'Store #3: ' + response.routes[0].legs[2].end_address;
      response.routes[0].legs[3].end_address = 'Store #4: ' + response.routes[0].legs[3].end_address;
      response.routes[0].legs[4].end_address = 'Store #5: ' + response.routes[0].legs[4].end_address;
      response.routes[0].legs[5].end_address = 'Store #6: ' + response.routes[0].legs[5].end_address;
      response.routes[0].legs[6].end_address = 'Store #7: ' + response.routes[0].legs[6].end_address;
      response.routes[0].legs[7].end_address = 'Store #8' + response.routes[0].legs[7].end_address;
      // directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);


      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      var route = response.routes[0];
      var summaryPanel = document.getElementById('directions-panel');
      directionsDisplay.setPanel(summaryPanel);
    } else {
      window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
    }
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="directions-panel"></div>
```